# If I run `docker-compose up` do I need a Dockerfile in the directory as well as a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Do I absolutely need to have a Dockerfile in my directory when using the command `docker-compose up`? I don't believe a Dockerfile is necessary but want to be sure.

If I only have a docker-compose.yml file using pre-built images, there would be no need for a Dockerfile.

Correct me please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You re right, Dockerfile is not necessary. Docker Compose uses YAML file, typically named docker-compose.yml to define what your mutliple-container application should look like.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

docker-compose lets you choose between the 2 options

- build the container from a specified image:

  ```
  services:
    example:
      image: your/imagename
  ```
- build the container out of a Dockerfile:

  ```
  services:
    example:
      build: 
        context: path/to/Dockerfile/dir
        dockerfile: Dockerfile #here you specify the name of your Dockerfile file
  ```

Comment: nope, option three is to define a single compose file does all the job. in that case a docker file is not needed. but ofc it is not very tidy. Put each container defination in the seprate docker files are cleaner.